# Critique my Realm to RxJava 2 Flowable method

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm fairly new to RxJava so I was hoping someone with a bit more knowledge could tear apart my method for getting a Flowable from a RealmResults, maintaining a reference to the resource for the lifetime of the Flowable and then disposing of it at the end. I'd be interested to know any errors I've made. The motivation behind this was to be able to subscribe to live realm queries without exposing Realm to the rest of the app.
One thing I'm not too keen on is that the Realm instance is passed into the function and then the Flowable manages closing it, rather than the caller managing closing it, but I can't see a way of closing the Realm instance in the calling class without either maintaining a seperate reference to it or wrapping the whole thing in another Flowable.using which seems a bit ugly.

```
public class RxRealm {

private static class ResultsResource<T extends RealmModel> {
    final Realm realm;
    final RealmResults<T> results;

    ResultsResource(Realm realm, RealmResults<T> results) {
        this.realm = realm;
        this.results = results;
    }
}

public static <T extends RealmModel> Flowable<RealmResults<T>> asFlowable(final Realm realm, final RealmResults<T> results) {
    return Flowable.using(new Callable<ResultsResource>() {
        @Override
        public ResultsResource call() throws Exception {
            return new ResultsResource<>(realm, results);
        }
    }, new Function<ResultsResource, Publisher<? extends RealmResults<T>>>() {
        @Override
        public Publisher<? extends RealmResults<T>> apply(@NonNull ResultsResource resultsResource) throws Exception {
            return Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<RealmResults<T>>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(@NonNull final FlowableEmitter<RealmResults<T>> emitter) throws Exception {
                    final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> changeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChange(RealmResults<T> element) {
                            if (!emitter.isCancelled()) {
                                emitter.onNext(element);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    results.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                }
            }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
        }
    }, new Consumer<ResultsResource>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull ResultsResource resource) throws Exception {
            resource.results.removeAllChangeListeners();
            resource.realm.close();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Usage:

```
public Flowable<Integer> getUnreadMessages(final String matchingId) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmQuery<Message> query = realm.where(Message.class)
            .equalTo("read", false);
    if (matchingId != null) {
        query.equalTo("id", matchingId);
    }
    RealmResults<Message> results = query.findAllAsync();
    return RxRealm.asFlowable(realm, results)
            .map(new Function<RealmResults<Message>, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer apply(@NonNull RealmResults<Message> realmResults) throws Exception {
                    return realmResults.size();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: it looks fine to me, which is actually super-uncommon. Well done! Only thing I wonder about is if it should be `isCancelled()` vs `isUnsubscribed()`, I usually see it with the latter.